# Algorithmicx Nested FOR loop in pseudocode

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, pseudocode, algpseudocode

*I have been trying to format the pseudocode below combining **algorithmicx** and **algpseudocode** commands as well as following another related post*

[algorithmicx or algpseudocode custom command indentation within a while loop or if statement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182948/algorithmicx-or-algpseudocode-custom-command-indentation-within-a-while-loop-or/182954?newreg=405f4ac5fc754b8cbffca8d347645143])[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBTlJ.png)

*The following pseudocode is what I am trying to reproduce.*

[image: Algorithm 1]

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicgenerate{\textbf{GENERATE}}
\algnewcommand\GENERATE[1]{\State\algorithmicgenerate\ #1}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicset{\textbf{SET}}
\algnewcommand\SET[1]{\State\algorithmicset\ #1}
\algloop{FOR}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
 \GENERATE{$S_t^{(i)} \qquad ,i=1,...,I,t=1,...,M$}
 \SET{$C_t^0(S_t^{(i)})=0 \qquad
 ,i=1,...,I,t=1,...,M$}
 \SET{$C_{M+1}^n(S_{M+1}^{(i)})=0 \qquad ,i=1,...,I,n=0,1,...,N$}
 \SET{$\hat{\Phi}_t^{(n)}(S_t^{(i)})=0 \qquad, i=1,...,I,t=1,...,M,n=0,1,...,N$}
 \FOR{$\quad t=M,...,1$}
  \SET{$\iota_t^{(i)} = \arg\max_{a_t^{(i)}\in A}\{P(S_t^{(i)};a_t^{(i)})\} \qquad ,i=1,...,I$}
  \FOR{$\, n=\max(1,N-t),...,N$}

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Which compiles to 
[image: Ouput]

*As you can see Line 7 would not allow me to nest a second FOR loop indented at the same level as Line 6.

Are there any custom commands more suitable for what I am trying to achieve as i honestly find it a bit confusing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the correct code for an for loop in your case would be:

```
  \For{$\, n=\max(1,N-t),...,N$}
    \SET{$\iota_t^{(i)} = \arg\max_{a_t^{(i)}\in A}\{P(S_t^{(i)};a_t^{(i)})\} \qquad ,i=1,...,I$}
  \EndFor
```

Please notice the lower letter in `\For` and `\EndFor`.

To get the For loop commands printed in capital letters use the following two commands:

```
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicfor{\textbf{FOR}} % <=======================
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicend{\textbf{END}} % <=======================
```

Please see the following complete MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicgenerate{\textbf{GENERATE}}
\algnewcommand\GENERATE[1]{\State\algorithmicgenerate\ #1}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicset{\textbf{SET}}
\algnewcommand\SET[1]{\State\algorithmicset\ #1}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicfor{\textbf{FOR}} % <=======================
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicend{\textbf{END}} % <=======================


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\GENERATE{$S_t^{(i)} \qquad ,i=1,...,I,t=1,...,M$}
\SET{$C_t^0(S_t^{(i)})=0 \qquad
 ,i=1,...,I,t=1,...,M$}
\SET{$C_{M+1}^n(S_{M+1}^{(i)})=0 \qquad ,i=1,...,I,n=0,1,...,N$}
\SET{$\hat{\Phi}_t^{(n)}(S_t^{(i)})=0 \qquad, i=1,...,I,t=1,...,M,n=0,1,...,N$}
\For{$\quad t=M,...,1$}
  \SET{$\iota_t^{(i)} = \arg\max_{a_t^{(i)}\in A}\{P(S_t^{(i)};a_t^{(i)})\} \qquad ,i=1,...,I$}
  \For{$\, n=\max(1,N-t),...,N$}
    \SET{$\iota_t^{(i)} = \arg\max_{a_t^{(i)}\in A}\{P(S_t^{(i)};a_t^{(i)})\} \qquad ,i=1,...,I$}
  \EndFor
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helps!